# OpenLdap Master / Master Replication Stops When Node Goes Offline

Tags: openldap

I'm currently using Ubuntu 10.04 (I've set this up on RHEL 5.x but the config is way different in Ubuntu).

Anyway, at first I figured I had everything working. When I made an update to ldap01 I immediately saw the change on ldap02. However, if I take down slapd on ldap02 (or 01) and I add LDAP entries into ldap01, then bring ldap02's slapd process back online I never see the entries created while slapd was down on ldap02. New entries continue to propigate between ldap01 and ldap02 and long as both servers have the slapd process running, but the entries created when slapd was down on ldap02 never propagate to 02.

Here are my configs and ldap versions:

ii  slapd                             2.4.21-0ubuntu5.7                 OpenLDAP server (slapd)

---- /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif -----

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 deacdc79
dn: olcDatabase={0}config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth manage by * break
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymou
 s auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net" write by * none
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net" write b
 y * read
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: 19eb3cc6-3898-1031-954c-351a2fbb42e9
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20120522202605Z
olcSyncrepl: {0}rid=001 provider="ldap://ldap-01:389" type=refreshAndPer
 sist retry="5 5 300 +" searchbase="cn=config" attrs="*,+" bindmethod=simple b
 inddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net" credentials="secret"
olcSyncrepl: {1}rid=002 provider="ldap://ldap-02:389" type=refreshAndPer
 sist retry="5 5 300 +" searchbase="cn=config" attrs="*,+" bindmethod=simple b
 inddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net" credentials="secret"
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
entryCSN: 20120528195647.027315Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net
modifyTimestamp: 20120528195647Z
```

---- /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config/olcOverlay={0}syncprov.ldif ----

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 807029fa
dn: olcOverlay={0}syncprov
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: {0}syncprov
olcSpNoPresent: TRUE
structuralObjectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
entryUUID: 3be00cb6-3dee-1031-8f60-519aa1b6f74f
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net
createTimestamp: 20120529152514Z
entryCSN: 20120529152514.987191Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net
modifyTimestamp: 20120529152514Z
```

---- /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif ----

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 1b0a3130
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=net
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymou
 s auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net" write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net" write b
 y * read
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net
olcRootPW:: e1NTSEF9Ni9IZWJCczRTbmJQYlc4NHFOMWxHWUI5NVNoVUl4U20=
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcDbConfig: {0}set_cachesize 0 2097152 0
olcDbConfig: {1}set_lk_max_objects 1500
olcDbConfig: {2}set_lk_max_locks 1500
olcDbConfig: {3}set_lk_max_lockers 1500
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
structuralObjectClass: olcHdbConfig
entryUUID: 19ebfdc8-3898-1031-9554-351a2fbb42e9
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20120522202605Z
olcSyncrepl: {0}rid=001 provider="ldap://ldap-01:389" type=refreshAndPer
 sist retry="5 5 300 +" searchbase="dc=example,dc=net" attrs="*,+" bindmeth
 od=simple binddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net" credentials="secret"
olcSyncrepl: {1}rid=002 provider="ldap://ldap-02:389" type=refreshAndPer
 sist retry="5 5 300 +" searchbase="dc=example,dc=net" attrs="*,+" bindmeth
 od=simple binddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net" credentials="secret"
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
entryCSN: 20120528195647.026244Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName:  cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net
modifyTimestamp: 20120528195647Z
```

----- /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb/olcOverlay={0}syncprov.ldif ----

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 807029fa
dn: olcOverlay={0}syncprov
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: {0}syncprov
olcSpNoPresent: TRUE
structuralObjectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
entryUUID: 3be00cb6-3dee-1031-8f60-519aa1b6f74f
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net
createTimestamp: 20120529152514Z
entryCSN: 20120529152514.987191Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net
modifyTimestamp: 20120529152514Z
```

Comment: Upgraded my version of OpenLDAP and my problem went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded my version of OpenLDAP and my problem went away